# Custom side menu show/hide flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to create an admin panel on web app. In Admin page i want to always display a side menu and in app bar i have icon button, i want this button to hide/show the side menu and when I hide menu need to expand container, when show shrink. My code

```
    class AdminPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdminPage createState() => _AdminPage();
}

bool isColapsed = true;

class _AdminPage extends State<AdminPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {

              })
        ],
      ),

      // drawer: Drawer(),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('content'),
            ),
          ),
          menu(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my cutom menu widget:

```
Widget menu(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        width: 250.0,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('page1'),
                  ),
                ],
              ) 
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: use scaffold's drawer property, give your menu as a child to drawer

Comment: Yes! Flutter's Drawer can help you with this.